# What is the difference between view.post() and view.getHandler().post() on Android?

Tags: android, android-view, android-handler

Documentation about `view.post()` says:

> Causes the Runnable to be added to the message queue. The runnable
>   will be run on the user interface thread.

`view.getHandler()` returns the following:

> A handler associated with the thread **running** the View.

I understand views can be created in a background thread, but they will always **run** on the UI thread. Which implies view.getHandler() should always return a handler associated with UI thread - essentially making view.getHandler().post() and view.post() posting to the same MessageQueue.

Why should I ever use view.getHandler().post() ?

Comment: Android is open source... https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#L13928

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't much difference other than `getHandler().post()` can throw you to a `NullPointerException` since it can return null.

```
/**
 * @return A handler associated with the thread running the View. This
 * handler can be used to pump events in the UI events queue.
 */
public Handler getHandler() {
    final AttachInfo attachInfo = mAttachInfo;
    if (attachInfo != null) {
        return attachInfo.mHandler;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Meanwhile, this simply redirects under the same conditions, but returns a boolean.

```
/**
 * <p>Causes the Runnable to be added to the message queue.
 * The runnable will be run on the user interface thread.</p>
 *
 * @param action The Runnable that will be executed.
 *
 * @return Returns true if the Runnable was successfully placed in to the
 *         message queue.  Returns false on failure, usually because the
 *         looper processing the message queue is exiting.
 *
 * @see #postDelayed
 * @see #removeCallbacks
 */
public boolean post(Runnable action) {
    final AttachInfo attachInfo = mAttachInfo;
    if (attachInfo != null) {
        return attachInfo.mHandler.post(action);
    }

    // Postpone the runnable until we know on which thread it needs to run.
    // Assume that the runnable will be successfully placed after attach.
    getRunQueue().post(action);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: One difference is that View.post caches the action in a queue if the Thread is not attached to the view, as per `getRunQueue().post(action);`